# "Could not chdir to home directory /home/me: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, bash, users, home-directory, adduser

I am using 12.04 on my server.

I created a new user using `adduser me` and `passwd me` and added it to sudo.

When I log in this is what I see.

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/me: No such file or directory    
$
```

I type `bash` and it begins to look "normal"

```
$ bash
me@server:/$
```

How can I avoid typing `bash` every time I login?

Comment: how did you create the new user?

Comment: that answer is not at all related to this question and does not help me.

Comment: What command you used to create the user? Also add to your question the output of `cat /etc/passwd`.

Comment: adduser me, passwd me

Comment: Please add the output of `getent passwd $USER` to your question

Answer (score 31):

`adduser` is too basic and doesn't set the defaults properly. It's recommended to use `useradd` whenever is possible. You can remove the new user and create it again  with `useradd -D me` or repair it yourself:

```
sudo mkdir /home/me
sudo usermod --shell /bin/bash --home /home/me me
sudo chown -R me:me /home/me
cp /etc/skel/.* /home/me/
```

If you had used `getent passwd me` as Florian suggested you should have seen something like this:

```
sudo getent passwd me
boggus:x:1002:1002::/home/me:/bin/sh
```

And `ls /home` wouldn't shown the user directory as your error:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/me: No such file or directory
```

Comment: however at the last step I get `cp: cannot stat `/etc/skel/*': No such file or directory` what does this do?

Comment: when I do `useradd -D me` it just outputs list of arguments. I have ran `userdel me` before

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy passwd`.

Comment: @ddd also, you sure is `user` then `add` not `add` then `user`? Please use copy paste to be sure.

Comment: following this instruction did not successfully resolve the problem.

Comment: @ddd but then tell what went wrong... edit your question and add the information...

Comment: @ddd you missed the '.'. What you needed to do was cp /etc/skel/.* /home/me/
 not cp /etc/skel/* /home/me/

Comment: @Braiam, I had similar issue and went through your instruction. The last line(cp /etc/skel/.* /home/me/) gives me error: 1. cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/etc/skel/.' 2. cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/etc/skel/..'   any idea?

Comment: @Shannon The copy worked on the three hidden files (.profile, .bashrc, .bash_logout), and (properly) failed to copy the directories "." (chrrent directory) and ".." (parent directory).   Every directory gets the . and .. automatically, so the command worked.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get this problem resolved is to delete the user and use this command to create the new user

```
useradd -m -d /home/me -s /bin/bash -G sudo me
```

This command creates a home directory and add bin/bash as the default shell for your new user. In addition it gives the new user sudo privileges.